# duplicate entry: android/support/annotation/DimenRes.class

Tags: android, android-studio

Here is my `gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile files('libs/acra-4.5.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/GoogleConversionTrackingSdk-2.2.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/gcm.jar')
    compile project(':libraries:AdvancwWebview')
    compile project(':libraries:SamsungBadger')
    compile project(':libraries:simple-crop-image-lib')
    compile project(path: ':libraries:simple-crop-image-lib')
    compile project(':libraries:DropboxChooserSDK')
    compile project(':libraries:libraryPullToReferesh')
    compile project(':libraries:StandOut')
    compile project(':libraries:google-play-services_lib')
    compile project(':libraries:ResideMenu')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0'
    compile project(path: ':Simple Facebook')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.0.0"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled = true
    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }
}
```

I switch my job. I got an Android code which was developed in Eclipse now I have to convert this code in android studio. However I am able to do that successfully but when I am trying to creating an apk it is showing error. Code is working on my device.

Comment: You question is too broad. Narrow it down for better answers. Also include error logs to help users understand your problem.

Comment: What is the exact error being shown?

Comment: @Neena did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

try to replace     `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0'` with `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'`